# MySQL: Are Multiple Deletes Possible and is my example correct?

Tags: mysql, foreign-keys, cascading-deletes

I found this article on cascading deletes (http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-on-delete-cascade/) and it answered a lot of my initial questions but now I have another one. I don't have anyone to confirm with except you folks so I do appreciate the feedback.

Scenario:

- Master User Table (masterTable)
- Supporting Table 1 (subTable1)
- Supporting Table 2 (subTable2)
- Support... you get the idea. (subTable...)

If a user is removed from masterTable and cascading is setup, the user records should be removed from the supporting table.

Now, back to reference back to the link I posted, I took their code and added additional tables to test the multiple cascading delete using their code plus a little extra that I added (the additional supporting tables).

**Question** While I did confirm that my sql statements below do work and achieve the result I'm after, is what I did below valid or is there better/more efficient way of doing multiple cascade deletes?

```
CREATE TABLE buildings (
    building_no INT PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
    building_name VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    address VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE rooms (
    room_no INT PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
    room_name VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    building_no INT NOT NULL,
    FOREIGN KEY (building_no)
        REFERENCES buildings (building_no)
        ON DELETE CASCADE
);

CREATE TABLE rooms1 (
    room_no INT PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
    room_name VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    building_no INT NOT NULL,
    FOREIGN KEY (building_no)
        REFERENCES buildings (building_no)
        ON DELETE CASCADE
);

CREATE TABLE rooms2 (
    room_no INT PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
    room_name VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    building_no INT NOT NULL,
    FOREIGN KEY (building_no)
        REFERENCES buildings (building_no)
        ON DELETE CASCADE
);

INSERT INTO buildings(building_name,address)
VALUES('ACME Headquaters','3950 North 1st Street CA 95134'),
    ('ACME Sales','5000 North 1st Street CA 95134');

SELECT * FROM buildings;

INSERT INTO rooms(room_name,building_no)
VALUES('Amazon',1),
    ('War Room',1),
    ('Office of CEO',1),
    ('Marketing',2),
    ('Showroom',2);

INSERT INTO rooms1(room_name,building_no)
VALUES('Bedroom',1),
    ('Kitchen',1),
    ('Game Room',1),
    ('Lounge',2),
    ('Gym',2);

INSERT INTO rooms2(room_name,building_no)
VALUES('Purple',1),
    ('Blue',1),
    ('Red',1),
    ('Yellow',2),
    ('Green',2);

SELECT * FROM rooms;
SELECT * FROM rooms1;
SELECT * FROM rooms2;

DELETE FROM buildings
WHERE
    building_no = 2;
```

Comment: Just found this link on applying the DELETE ON CASCADE to existing tables. http://steveminordesign.com/2012/06/add-on-delete-cascade-to-foreign-key-mysql/

Comment: It depends on your system .If your room table do not have further  child tables(eg: room_bookings) then you can do the cascading.

Comment: Thanks for replying. So it doesn't matter if the cascade affects one table or 10, the cascading process is the same?

Comment: Yes, you just need to make sure that your child records are not orphan.

Comment: Perfect, thank you.